# Why does pancreatin affect the pH of milk?

Tags: enzymes, experiment, ph

I just finished a lab for college and I was really intrigued by this. Since we're in a rush to finish the semester on time my professor didn't go into details much she just said something about fatty acids? But I'd like something more in depth because honestly this is the only lab I've liked this semester and it's just fascinating to me. I googled it but it was a whole bunch of other stuff coming up and I want a direct answer on why this happens.

Lab: For the lab, we started out with two test tubes one filled with water and milk and the other with a pancreatin solution and milk. We then added bromothymol blue to each test tube and put it in a warm water bath for 40 minutes then we just recorded our results. We just had to explain what reaction was being used and what would happen with different types of dairy products. For each test tube with the pancreatin solution and milk it changed color usually to orange or yellow, showing that the pH had dropped.

This is NOT for a homework answer I'm genuinely just curious about the mechanics of it all.

Thank you!! :)

Comment: Describe the lab a little bit - what did you do, and what did you find?

Comment: @MattDMo For the lab we started out with test tubes that we filled with two test tubes one filled with water and milk and the other with a pancreatin solution. We then added bromothymol blue to each test tubes and put it in a warm water bath then we just recorded our results. We just had to explain what reaction was being used and what would happen with different types of dairy products.

Comment: @MaximilianPress not really? Sorry but I'd like for something more in detail and most of the responses are people getting mad about it being a homework question.

Comment: @wheeinsoup it's true that there are no detailed answers on that question. However, in this community we tend to consider one copy of each question as enough, and the one short answer there probably gives enough information for you to be able to do some research. If you still find something confusing you are very welcome to bring your research and to explain what about it is confusing and we will try to help if we can.

Comment: @MaximilianPress okay! thank you for the help :)